# Check if exists the same value in multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say i have an array like this:

```
$array = array(
  0 => 
    array (
      'value' =>  '1' ,
      'name' =>  'dasdfa sadfa' ),

   1=> Array (
      'value' =>  'adresa@gmail.com' ,
      'name' =>  'd2' ),
  21 => 
    array(
      'value' =>  'adresa@gmail.com' ,
      'name' =>  'name1`' ),

  23 => 
    array(
      'value' =>  'popescu.catalina@gmail.com' ,
      'name' =>  'POPESCU CATALINA' ),
  24 => 
    array(
      'value' =>  'popescu.catalina@gmail.com' ,
      'name' =>  'POPESCU CATALINA' ),

  26 => 
    array(
      'value' =>  'ricardo.ramos@amadeus.com',
      'name' =>  '43414 Test01'),
  27 => 
    array(
      'value' =>  'sta3no213123ct3av@yahoo.com',
      'name' =>  'oct oct' )

);
```

I want to know if exists duplicated value  in array with key 'value' I know how to do this if i want a specified value but general no. The result must be an array with no duplicated values(eg:

```
    $array = array(
  0 => 
    array (
      'value' =>  '1' ,
      'name' =>  'dasdfa sadfa' ),

   1=> Array (
      'value' =>  'adresa@gmail.com' ,
      'name' =>  'd2' ),

  23 => 
    array(
      'value' =>  'popescu.catalina@gmail.com' ,
      'name' =>  'POPESCU CATALINA' ),

  26 => 
    array(
      'value' =>  'ricardo.ramos@amadeus.com',
      'name' =>  '43414 Test01'),
  27 => 
    array(
      'value' =>  'sta3no213123ct3av@yahoo.com',
      'name' =>  'oct oct' )

);`
```

Please help me.

This is my try

```
function has_dupes($array){
 $dupe_array = array();
 foreach($array as $val){
  if(++$dupe_array[$val] > 1){
   return true;
  }
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: please share what you tried then we can help you in modify that with better way....

Comment: please provide better description

Comment: I want to remove the key from "main array" if value from key 'value' is duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
    $array = array(
  '0' => 
    array (
      'value' =>  '1' ,
      'name' =>  'dasdfa sadfa' ),

   '1'=> Array (
      'value' =>  'adresa@gmail.com' ,
      'name' =>  'd2' ),
  '21' => 
    array(
      'value' =>  'adresa@gmail.com' ,
      'name' =>  'name1`' ),

  '23' => 
    array(
      'value' =>  'popescu.catalina@gmail.com' ,
      'name' =>  'POPESCU CATALINA' ),
  '24' => 
    array(
      'value' =>  'popescu.catalina@gmail.com' ,
      'name' =>  'POPESCU CATALINA' ),

  '26' => 
    array(
      'value' =>  'ricardo.ramos@amadeus.com',
      'name' =>  '43414 Test01'),
  '27' => 
    array(
      'value' =>  'sta3no213123ct3av@yahoo.com',
      'name' =>  'oct oct' )

);
$array = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
```

Comment: This is not ok because when i have two values equal but name different doesn't eliminate this!

Comment: This is to eliminate duplicate array, if u want to eliminate duplicate with value then use array_filter http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: I don't understand how to use array_filter with your solution

Comment: you can define some user defined function which will callback in array_filter. i.e array_filter($array, 'your_function')

Comment: Oky that i understood, but the problem is the user callback. I don't really know how to make this :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array_unique($array);
print_r($result);
```

And if you want to store all unique data in one array do it like this:

```
//declare $array
$unique_array = array();
foreach ($array as  $key => $type) {
    foreach($type as $vale => $name) {
        if ($vale == 'value') {
            //echo $name . '<br>';
            array_push($unique_array, $name);
        }
    }
}
$result = array_unique($unique_array);
foreach ($result as $res) {
    echo $res . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: @OsomA, you didn't exactly say what you want if there some the same data!

Comment: I want to remove the key from main array, you can see the example up!

Comment: Thank you, it is ok, but now what i need, i will rewrite myself

Comment: Yeap, this is the main idea, understand your "stack" moment, keep in mind, and resolve it by yourself

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$values = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));

foreach ($values as $key => $value)
  {
    if ( is_array($value) )
    {
       $values[$key] = $value;
    }
  }

print_r($values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$unique_data = array(); // the result array
$duplicate_data = array();

$seen = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
    $value = $arr['value'];
    if (!isset($seen[$value])) {
        $seen[$value] = '';
        $unique_data[$key] = $arr;
    } else {
        $duplicate_data[$key] = $arr; // optional
    }
}
unset($seen); // optional in function scope
```

Comment: please add some explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem, this will help others in the future

Comment: The code is self-explanatory. But it simply builds a new array, omitting duplicates which occur later.